# How to disable Cassandra on RHQ 4.9 and store measurements on Postgres

Tags: jboss, rhq

I'm triyng to get all the measurement data on rhq and I think that the easiest way to do this is forcing  rhq to save the measurements on postgres as It did in older versions.

How can I disable Cassandra on RHQ 4.9 and store measurements on Postgres?

If this is no possible there's another way to easily export all measurement data to a relational database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the Cassandra-base Storage Node backend on RHQ 4.9 and up.

Depending on your needs, you could write a RHQ CLI script to work with the MeasurementDataManager. But if you want to extract all the raw data, you'll have to connect to the Storage Node and execute CQL requests.